# Make StickyGridHeadersGridView layout center aligned?

Tags: android, android-gridview

I'm using StickyGridHeadersGridView for showing booking slots in an application. Thing is it is working fine and all, but the slots are placed like they are in match parent. At a time mostly 3 or 4 slots will be shown. So, if it's centrally aligned it will look more pleasing to watch. Tried doing many tweaks with no help. Posting the xml code below.

main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/lin_slots_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <include
            android:id="@+id/layoutGrid"
            layout="@layout/slot_grid_slide"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:visibility="visible" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

layoutGrid

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/lightgrey"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <com.bestdocapp.kiosk_opd.utils.stickygridheaders.StickyGridHeadersGridView
        android:id="@+id/session"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@color/bmh_home_background_color"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:columnWidth="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
        android:numColumns="5"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:verticalSpacing="2dp"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Need to make it centrally aligned.

Comment: can you attach a image?

Comment: yes, please check the following link. Not able to centrally align it. Annoying really.
https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/3/1/bde87ac3768499114ffd2e30e225cb5c-full.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. I've changed some of its properties . so please check this is what you want ?

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/lightgrey"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <com.bestdocapp.kiosk_opd.utils.stickygridheaders.StickyGridHeadersGridView
        android:id="@+id/session"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@color/bmh_home_background_color"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
        android:numColumns="5"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:verticalSpacing="2dp"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hello tried it. But currently a grey screen is only present now. No slots are showing. I think it is hidden now.

Comment: @ClintPaul  you need to adjust your column width according to your inner xml size . so updated my answer with column width . you can set as per your xml

Comment: Hello. I tried out the new changes also. But still no help. The slots are not showing yet. It is covered by a greyish background.